# Parsing in compiler design

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

As far as I know, Left recursion is not a problem for LR parser.And I know that an ambiguous grammar can't be parsed by any kind of parser.So if I have an ambiguous grammar as follows,how can I remove ambiguity so that I can check if this grammar is SLR(1) or not?

E->E+E|E-E|(E)|id

And one more question,is left factoring needed for a grammar to check if the grammar is LL(1) or SLR(1)?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Any parser generator you are likely to encounter will be able to handle the ambiguities in your grammar simply.

Your grammar produces shift/reduce conflicts. These are not necessarily a problem (as are reduce/reduce conflicts). The default action on a shift/reduce conflict in every parser generator is to shift, which solves your problem. There are usually mechanisms (as in YACC or Bison) to ignore this as a warning.

You can remove the conflicts in your grammar by setting up multiple levels of expressions so that you force the precedence of the operators.